# Difference between cbind with dataframe subset or indicating each column separately?

Tags: r, cbind, manova

What is the difference between these two lines of codes?

```
varname1 <- cbind(df.name$var1, df.name$var2, df.name$var3)

varname2 <- cbind(df.name[1:3])
```

If I then try to use the next function I get an "invalid type (list) for variable "varname2".

This is the next function I try to use:

```
manova(varname ~ indepvar.snack+judge+rep,data = df.name)
```

So why does varname1 works and varname2 not?

Comment: Maybe it's because their classes are different? `varname1` is a matrix whereas `varname2` is a dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Nulling my previous answer as I originaly thought you are column binding a series of columns in to a single columned dataframe.*

check `str(varname1)` since it results in matrix while `str(varname2)` is dataframe.

manova is accepting matrix-type variable as argument.
do:

```
varname2 <- as.matrix(varname2)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, does it for you? What is the difference between [1:3] and [,1:3]? Thank you!

Comment: based on what I tried, actually the first one (`cbind(df$var1, df$var2`) results in matrix and second one results in data.frame. have you do `str(varname1)` and `str(varname2)`?

Comment: str(varname1) is num for me and the other one is a dataframe.. How can I change the dataframe into a num? Then the next function probably works.

Comment: as per my understanding, manova is accepting matrix type of argument. Can you try `varname2 <- as.matrix(varname2)`?

Comment: can you accept my answer if it helps and works? Thanks. @Papie